# Run multiple Gearman Process using multiprocess module in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gearman

I want to run multiple gearman worker process using python`s multiprocessing module , but it seems like the process is executing in sequential mode. If i run individual worker.py programs in several terminals , then it is working fine. But i want to lessen the burden of manually specifying worker.py  in soo many terminals. Is there any alternative for this ?

```
import sys , os , simplejson
from fabric import *
from fabric.api import *
import gearman
from gearman import GearmanWorker
from multiprocessing import Pool


##--Global Variables--##
#Spawing minimun 5 worker threads for Gearman



#executing the Job. gmJob consist of dict[host , cmd , pass] 
def exe_job(gmWorker , gmJob ):
 print " the worker process is " , os.getpid()
 d = simplejson.loads(gmJob.data)
 env.host_string = d['host'] 
 env.password = d['pass']  #will store the password .
 cmds = d['cmd']
 print cmds
 for i in cmds:
  sudo (i )  # using fabric functions to ssh into system  
 return "job sucessfull"

def start_exe():
 #woker node id to be specified in here
 gm_worker = gearman.GearmanWorker(['localhost:4730'])
 #gm_worker.set_client_id('client1')
 gm_worker.register_task('exe_job',exe_job)
 gm_worker.work()


if __name__ == '__main__':
 p = Pool(5)
 result = p.apply_async(start_exe)
 print result.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an answer to this, either, so I dug into things and figured out that you basically have to use a queue to track which processes you have open and which have closed (an error in the case of a gearman worker).  Anyway, I built it into a module and posted it on pypi.  It's still very much a work in progress but I'll try to get to adding documentation and examples in the next day or so:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmtasks
- https://github.com/ex-nerd/gmtasks

I also included client and worker classes that communicate via json (I mention this because your example seems to use json).

Let me know what you think.  I could definitely use a few more sets of eyes on this to find bugs or tell me where I did something completely crazy with the code.